# Python: Reading csv file as list of dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file with data like below:

```
[",P1,P2\n2019-08-01 01:01:00,22.95,4.12\n2019-08-01 01:03:00,23.8,4.22\n 
2019-08-01 01:06:00,26.48,4.67\n2019-08-01 01:08:00,25.15,4.25\n
2020-08-01 01:40:00,2.8,2.6\n 2020-08-01 01:42:00,3.8,3.5\n
2020-08-01 01:48:00,3.57,3.0\n2020-08-01 01:50:00,3.13,2.93\n 2020-08-01 01:53:00,5.5,3.13\n
2020-08-01 01:55:00,5.0,3.23\n2020-08-01 01:58:00,3.4,3.2\n',
", ",P1,P2\n2019-08-01 01:01:00,57.5,5.37\n2019-08-01 01:03:00,52.97,4.0\n
2019-08-01 01:06:00,55.83,4.4\n2019-08-01 01:08:00,53.5,4.4\n...]
```

which contains P1 and P2 values for 16 sensors.
How can I read it as list of dataframe like below:

```
[                        P1    P2
 2019-08-01 01:01:00  22.95  4.12
 2019-08-01 01:03:00  23.80  4.22
 2019-08-01 01:11:00  23.85  3.77
 ...                    ...   ...
 2020-08-01 01:49:00   2.83  1.70
 2020-08-01 01:59:00   1.52  1.40
 
 [190689 rows x 2 columns],
                         P1     P2
 2019-08-01 01:02:00   8.90   8.20
 2019-08-01 01:12:00  12.03  10.83
 ...                    ...    ...
 2020-08-01 01:48:00   9.20   4.60
 2020-08-01 01:51:00   5.93   5.43
 2020-08-01 01:58:00   4.57   4.27
 
 [189709 rows x 2 columns],...]
```

Edit:
I tried to read using json:

```
p = json.load(codecs.open('pm_data.csv', 'r', 'utf-8-sig'))
```

the result was a list of str:

```
type(p)    
list

len(p)    
16

type(p[1])    
str

len(p[1])    
5714149

p:

[',P1,P2\n2019-08-01 01:01:00,22.95,4.12\n
2019-08-01 01:03:00,23.8,4.22\n
2019-08-01 01:06:00,26.48,4.67\n2019-08-01 01:08:00,25.15,4.25\n
2019-08-01 01:11:00,23.85,3.77\n2019-08-01 01:13:00,25.8,4.4\n
2019-08-01 01:16:00,25.12,3.83\n2019-08-01 01:18:00,23.92,4.2\n
2019-08-01 01:21:00,23.95,4.3\n2019-08-01 01:23:00,24.65,4.9\n
2019-08-01 01:26:00,26.37,4.5\n2019-08-01 01:28:00,23.85,4.15\n
2019-08-01 01:31:00,25.6,3.85\n2019-08-01 01:33:00,24.18,4.7\n
...]
```

Comment: You can use pandas and [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Please update the question to show what you've tried/researched on your own.

Comment: Why on *earth* do you try to read it as JSON if it's CSV? This is like trying to read an Excel spreadsheet with a Mercedes 300SL.